# A set without the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By definition, the empty set is a subset of every set, right? Then how would you interpret this set: $A\setminus\{\}$? On one hand it looks like a set without the empty set, on the other hand, the empty set is in every set... Can you explain?

Comment: The set difference $A\setminus B$ means you're removing the elements in $B$ from $A$. You're not removing the set $B$ itself from $A$. So $A\setminus\{\}$ means we remove everything in the empty set from $A$. So we're removing nothing, so it's still just $A$.

Comment: You can have all of the cake I have left once I've eaten it all. If I've eaten all the cake $A$, then the portion that's left is the empty subset of the cake. Removing all crumbs in that subset from the cake, what's left is the crumbs I have eaten - all of them. Every last one. The empty set is not a crumb in the cake, but it is a portion of the cake, or a subset of the cake.

Comment: Subset $\ne$ element.

Comment: A man walks down the street with a pocket full of change. He comes to a fountain and he throws every penny he has in his pocket into the fountain. As he walks away, he mumbles "I still have every penny I started with." How?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> By definition, the empty set is a subset of every set, right?

Yes.

> Then how would you interpret this set: $A\setminus\{\}$?

The set $A\setminus\{\}$ is the set of members of $A$ which are not members of $\{\}$. However, $\{\}$ has no members, so $A\setminus\{\}=A$.

> **On one hand it looks like a set without the empty set**, on the other hand, the empty set is in every set...

If you wish to remove the empty set from $A$, you should do $A\setminus\{\{\}\}$.

> On one hand it looks like a set without the empty set, on the other hand, **the empty set is in every set...**

The empty set is **not** a member of every set, it is a subset of every set. $A\subseteq B$ means that for all $x\in A$: $x\in B$. If $A=\{\}$, regardless of what kind of set $B$ is, this statement is always true. This is because there are no $x\in\{\}$.

Comment: In $A \setminus \{\{\}\}$, if you have a $B\subset A$, and given the rule that every set contains the empty set, wouldn't the empty set be in $B$ and thus in $A$ still?

Comment: @Alec: `given the rule that every set contains the empty set` What do you mean? Not every set contains the empty set. (for example, the empty set does not contain the empty set)

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the rule that the empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: @Alec: Do you have any other questions or clarifications?

Comment: @Regret: In $A \backslash${{}}, does it mean {} is an element of {{}} or a subset?

Comment: @infinitesimal: Nothing is a member of the empty set, hence the name. The statement $x\in\{\}$ is always false, so the statement "for all $x\in\{\}$:..." is always true.

Comment: @Arthur: Sorry for the late response. $\{\{\}\}$ is the set with only the empty set as its member.

Comment: @Arthur: If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Just write it
$$
A\setminus\{\}=\Big\{a~\mid~ a\in A \text{ and } a \not \in \{\} \Big\} =A
$$

Answer (score 2):

The notation $A-\{\}$ roughly translates to "the set $A$ without the elements of $\{\}$."  The difference is that the empty set is not an element of $A$ and this notation just means you're not removing any elements from your original set.

Comment: This is one of those ultra trivial constructions that's a quirk of our strange foundations.

Answer (score 2):

The construction $A\setminus B$ can be axiomatized as follows:

1. $(A\setminus B)\subseteq A$
2. $(A\setminus B)\cap B = \{\}$
3. $A\setminus B$ is the largest set satifisfying (1) and (2).

Condition (2) captures axiomatically the idea that "$B$ isn't in $A\setminus B$".  Consider replacing condition (2) with the axiom

- $B\not\subseteq(A\setminus B)$

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{2, 3\}$.  Then $\{1, 3\}$ and $\{1, 3\}$ are both subsets of $A$ satisfying the incorrect condition *, but we want the set difference to be smaller than either of them.  So we use condition (2), which says *none* of the elements of $B$ is in $A\setminus B$.

But if $B = \{\}$, condition (2) is just $(A\setminus \{\})\cap\{\} = \{\}$, which is true regardless of what $A\setminus\{\}$ is.  So we have conditions (1) and (3) left to fulfill: $(A\setminus\{\})\subseteq A$, and $A\setminus\{\}$ is the largest set satisfying (1).  But $A$ is the largest subset of $A$, so $A\setminus\{\} = A$.

Comment: i.e. $\,\ C\subseteq A\setminus B\iff C\subseteq A,\, C\cap B =\{\}\ \ $